# Discord Fetch Random message from a Channel [Python]

Tags: python, discord

The bot should fetch a random message from a diffrent channel and send it to the channel where the command was made.

Example: Im in #chat and it should fetch a random message from #memes and post it in #chat where I made the command.

Heres the code I made which doesn't really work.

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx, message_id, channel_id):
    guild = ctx.guild
    channel = guild.get_channel(int(672740818645417984))
    message = guild.fetch_message(random.choice(int(message_id)))
    message = await channel.fetch_message(int(message_id))
    await channel.send(message)
```

Currently as Error it can't get the message_id

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):

    channel = client.get_channel("channel id")

    allmes = []
    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
        allmes.append(message)

    randoms = random.choice(allmes).content

    await ctx.send(randoms)
```